# Only 4 Items in ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar with 5 Items but app (no matter horizontally or vertically) shows only 4 Item icons. Additional Item is visible after clicking More (ellipsis) button. I turned of Title and Home and still app displays only 4 Items on the right of the screen.

How to extend default space in ActionBar for custom Items?

[image]

Comment: What are you using for your action bar implementation? The native one, `appcompat-v7`, or something else? Your screenshot suggests "something else".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might simply be the case that you haven't set the android:showAsAction attribute for the menu items, so by default it is hiding them once there is a certain number. Try setting `android:showAsAction="always"` for all of the items.

Comment: Thank you. I missed showAsAction for one of the Item, and I changed to "always" for all of them.

Comment: @PawelMiechowiecki No worries, did this solve your problem?

Comment: Please could you mark this answer as correct then :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Yes menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="pl.waw.miechoo.gpsspeed2.MainActivity" 
>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_information"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:title="Info"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_screen_orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/synchronization"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_screen_orientation_string"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_screen_orientation_condensed_string">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:menuCategory="container"
            android:visible="true" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_screen_orientation_landscape"
                android:title="@string/menu_screen_orientation_landscape_string">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_screen_orientation_portrait"
                android:title="@string/menu_screen_orientation_portrait_string">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_screen_orientation_auto"
                android:title="@string/menu_screen_orientation_auto_string">
            </item>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_meause_unit_type"
    android:icon="@drawable/checklist"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/measureUnitType"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/measureUnitTypeCondensed">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:visible="true" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_mps"
                android:title="@string/menu_mps_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_kmph"
                android:title="@string/menu_kmph_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_mph"
                android:title="@string/menu_mph_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_fps"
                android:title="@string/menu_fps_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_knots"
                android:title="@string/menu_knots_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_mach"
                android:title="@string/menu_mach_string"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_c"
                android:title="@string/menu_c_string"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_hud"
    android:icon="@drawable/gear"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_hud">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:visible="true" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_hud_off"
                android:title="@string/menu_hud_off">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_hud_on"
                android:title="@string/menu_hud_on">
            </item>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_precision"
    android:icon="@drawable/compass"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_precission_string">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:visible="true" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_0"
                android:title="0">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_1"
                android:title="0,0">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_2"
                android:title="0,00">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_3"
                android:title="0,000">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_4"
                android:title="0,0000">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_5"
                android:title="0,00000">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_prec_6"
                android:title="0,000000">
            </item>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```